# Android volley get (ANY) user data from server after login

Tags: java, php, android, json, android-volley

I'm currently building an android app using android volley to handle network task. Right now i'm not sure how do i able to get the user data from the server after login. The only way for me to get it to work is that, i need to specify my URL username like `Username=abc`. Below is my java code.

**(Main)Profile Fragment.java**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

ProgressDialog dialog;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/profile.php?Username=abc";

private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    dialog.show();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    sendRequest();

    return rootView;

}

private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    Profile_Details pj = new Profile_Details(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    profile_details cl = new profile_details(getActivity(), profile_details.names, profile_details.date_of_birth,  profile_details.street_add, profile_details.postal_code, profile_details.city, profile_details.state, profile_details.country);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendRequest();
}

}
```

**Profile.php**

```
<?php

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','users');

$Username = $_GET["Username"];

$mysqli = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ("SELECT Name, Date_of_Birth, 
Street_Add, Postal_Code, City, State, Country
                       FROM personal_details INNER JOIN user_details ON 
user_details.User_ID = personal_details.User_ID 
                       WHERE Username=?");

$stmt->bind_param('s', $Username);
$stmt->execute();
/* bind variables to prepared statement */
$stmt->bind_result($Name, $Date_of_Birth, 
$Street_Add, $Postal_Code, $City, $State, $Country);
$rows = array();
/* fetch values */

while($stmt->fetch()) {
        array_push($rows, array('Name'=>$Name, 
                  'Date_of_Birth'=>$Date_of_Birth, 
                  'Street_Add'=>$Street_Add, 'Postal_Code'=>$Postal_Code, 
                  'City'=>$City, 'State'=>$State, 
                  'Country'=>$Country));
}

/* close statement */
$stmt->close();

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$rows));

?>
```

Additional info. I created the `personal details` table that is linked from `user details` table. I think the linking part is ok. Below is my json response.

**JSON**

```
{
"result": [{
    "Name": "John",
    "Date_of_Birth": "1995-05-09",
    "Street_Add": "abc street",
    "Postal_Code": "12345",
    "City": "def",
    "State": "ghi",
    "Country": "jkl"
}]
}
```

So how do i configure the java code that after i login, i can straight display the user profile that i do not need to specify a username at the end of `URL`.

**New update!**
I got a null object reference error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                       Process: com.androidnewlearner, PID: 2885
                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.HashMap com.androidnewlearner.content.SessionManager.getUserDetails()' on a null object reference
                                                           at com.androidnewlearner.mainactivity.ProfileFragment.sendRequest(ProfileFragment.java:84)
                                                           at com.androidnewlearner.mainactivity.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:74)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
                                                           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is my `SessionManager` java file. I copy only the line that error pointed to.

**SessionManager.java**

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    // Use hashmap to store user credentials
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // User name
    user.put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));

    // User password
    user.put(KEY_PASSWORD, pref.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}
```

**Updated Profile Fragment.java**

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

ProgressDialog dialog;
String url;

SessionManager session;
private String Username;
private String Acc_Pass;
SharedPreferences shared;

public ProfileFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    dialog.show();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview, container, false);
    //buttonGet = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonGet);
    //buttonGet.setOnClickListener(this);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    sendRequest(Username, Acc_Pass);  <------Here is the error
    shared= getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return rootView;

    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
}

private void sendRequest(String Username, String Acc_Pass){

    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();  <------Here is the error
    Username = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    Acc_Pass = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);

    RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleyController.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();

    String url = "http://192.168.1.6/json_dri_details2.php?Username="+Username+"&Acc_Pass="+Acc_Pass+"";

    url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    try {
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(url);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("Getting url info",""+url);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    Dri_Details pj = new Dri_Details(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    profile_details cl = new profile_details(getActivity(), profile_details.names, profile_details.date_of_birth,  profile_details.street_add, profile_details.postal_code, profile_details.city, profile_details.state, profile_details.country);
    listView.setAdapter(cl);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendRequest(Username, Acc_Pass);
}

}
```

Comment: I am not an expert at this, though what I can think of as a possible solution is storing the username and pass in an encrypted format in your DB. While making a server call pass the username and pass in `URL` in the same encrypted format.

Comment: Sorry. I did not get what you mean. I've been stuck for a long time, i need to quickly fix it.

Comment: Lemme understand your question, you don't want to pass username and password in URL?

Comment: Is it possible not to pass? Because right now if i put like this `"http://192.168.1.6/profile.php?Username=abc"` it will show the details of `abc` what if i login to another username `John`, it still show me the `abc` details. Then in order for me to get the username `John` details, i had to set the `URL` to `"http://192.168.1.6/profile.php?Username=John"`. I'm getting stuck, hope someone can help me with this, or is there any alternative way. Kindly guide me.

Comment: So if you have multiple accounts which you want to show them the code would  be `String username = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.username)).getText();` then create a URL `URL profileUrl = new URL ("http://192.168.1.6/profile.php? username=" + username);` This way you can get profile of entered username

Comment: I have updated my code now, and i get some error. I have pointed out the error on the newly updated `profilefragment.java`

Comment: Nevermind. I have successfully solve it! :)

Comment: How to mark this thread as solved/close?